# Object required Error When Looping through DIR()

Tags: excel, vba, loops

As stated I am getting an object required error when looping through a directory. Funny thing is that it is declared. I only starting getting this issue when I started looping through a folder and not just a worksheet. I tried activating the workbook but this didnt seem to work either. I moved things around to see if the compiler was being picky and nothing still. Maybe a fresh set of eyes will help me pinpoint my error?  Thanks

Code:

```
 Sub MultiDimArray()

 Dim Z As Long
 Dim A1 As Long
 Dim ws As Integer
 Dim wbk As Workbook
 Dim Filename As String
 Dim Path As String
 Dim myArray(9, 5) As String

 Path = "C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Desktop\doug\test\TheFolder"
 Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

 Do While Len(Filename) > 0
     Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
     wbk.Activate
     Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
     For i = 1 To ws
         For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
             For y = LBound(myArray, 2) To UBound(myArray, 2)
                     myArray(x, y) = "Position " & "x=" & x & ", y=" & y & ", z=" & Z & ", A1=" & A1
                     ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(x + 1, y + 1).Value = myArray(x, y)
             Next y
         Next x
         Z = Z + 1
     Next i
     wbk.Close True
     x = 0
     y = 0
     Z = 0
     A1 = A1 + 1
     Filename = Dir
 Loop
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hint: `Count` is not an object: `Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`. Looks like you kept the old variable name after changing its use.

Comment: Ahhhh I see. If I take "set" away form that line everything works fine.... Except the looping code doesnt actually execute. Ill play around some more and try and figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take Set away from Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

and that solves the object required issue.

ALSO

Turns out that :

```
 Path = "C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Desktop\doug\test\TheFolder"
```

should be

```
 Path = "C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Desktop\doug\test\TheFolder" & "\"
```

I seem to always miss that O_o

Comment: Not to be picky, but that's not an answer to your question, which was about an "Object Required" error.

Comment: well you couldve phrased your original comment as an answer and gotten rep.... At least I care to follow through on any remaining issues just in case someone one else cares.